# QGIS - Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin v.4.9.5 - When trying to create ROI getting Error[43]: Attribute table error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification

when I try to create a ROI within the Plugin: Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin, I am getting the Error: Attribute table error. Which means it is not creating MC ID / MC Info or C ID / C Info in the ROI list. So no attributes are created, but the weird thing is the signature list gets the correct informations.

So far I tried reeinstalling it, which didn't work. Any hints how to solve that problem?

Hope the picture makes my point more clear:

[image]

Still trying to solve this problem. I don't understand why it's not copying any attributes to my created ROIs in the ROI list.

When I try to delete the created ROI, following error appears: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'